# how can I reset a color tween in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

so I am trying to make a color tween animation where when the button is pressed, if the answer is correct on the text field, the background color will be green and then turns back into black, if not then the same thing will happen but red instead of green however I encountered a problem.
when I enter an answer, the color tween works, but when I do it again, nothing happens.
here's the entire code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'math_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<GameScreen> createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int n1 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
  int n2 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
  int lives = 3;
  int score = 0;
  FocusNode node = FocusNode();
  double sec = 60.00;
  dynamic isCorrect = null;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  late AnimationController ctrl;
  late Animation<Color?> clr;


  @override
  void initState(){

    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        sec=sec-0.01;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
    ctrl = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this,
    );
    clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Container(
          width: size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: size.height,
              width: size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: clr.value,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: getVerticalSize(
                          16.00,
                        ),
                        bottom: getVerticalSize(
                          20.00,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Container(
                              width: size.width,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: getHorizontalSize(
                                    16.00,
                                  ),
                                  right: getHorizontalSize(
                                    16.00,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: getVerticalSize(
                                          3.00,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: Row(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: [
                                          lives >= 1? Image.asset(
                                            "assets/heart.webp",
                                            height: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            width: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                          ): SizedBox(
                                            height: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            width: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          lives >= 2? Image.asset(
                                            "assets/heart.webp",
                                            height: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            width: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                          ): SizedBox(
                                            height: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            width: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          lives >= 3? Image.asset(
                                            "assets/heart.webp",
                                            height: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            width: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                          ): SizedBox(
                                            height: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                            width: getSize(
                                              32.00,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "Score: $score",
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white70,
                                        fontSize: getFontSize(
                                          24,
                                        ),
                                        fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: size.width,
                            height: getVerticalSize(
                              20
                            ),
                            child:
                            // Text(
                            //   "$sec",
                            //   maxLines: null,
                            //   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            //   style: TextStyle(
                            //     color: Colors.white70,
                            //     fontSize: getFontSize(
                            //       24,
                            //     ),
                            //     fontFamily: 'Inter',
                            //     fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            //   ),
                            // ),
                            LinearProgressIndicator(
                              value: sec/60,
                              color: sec/60 >= 0.5? Colors.green:Colors.red,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: getHorizontalSize(
                                96.00,
                              ),
                              top: getVerticalSize(
                                200.00,
                              ),
                              right: getHorizontalSize(
                                96.00,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              "${n1} x ${n2}",
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white70,
                                fontSize: getFontSize(
                                  64,
                                ),
                                fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    focusNode: node,
                    controller: controller,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onSubmitted: (value) async{
                      setState(() {
                        if(value == (n1 * n2).toString()){
                          score += 10;
                          n1 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
                          n2 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
                          WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
                            ctrl.forward();
                          });
                          print(true);
                        }
                        else {
                          lives -= 1;
                          WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
                            ctrl.forward();
                          });
                          print(false);
                        }

                      });
                      clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
                      controller.clear();
                      Future sleep(final Duration duration) async {
                        await Future.delayed(duration);
                      }
                      await sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
                      node.requestFocus();
                    },
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 48
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code that I'm focusing on is this

```
TextField(
                    focusNode: node,
                    controller: controller,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    onSubmitted: (value) async{
                      setState(() {
                        if(value == (n1 * n2).toString()){
                          score += 10;
                          n1 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
                          n2 = Random().nextInt(13) + 0;
                          WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
                            ctrl.forward();
                          });
                          print(true);
                        }
                        else {
                          lives -= 1;
                          WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
                            ctrl.forward();
                          });
                          print(false);
                        }

                      });
                      clr = ColorTween(begin: Colors.black).animate(ctrl);
                      controller.clear();
                      Future sleep(final Duration duration) async {
                        await Future.delayed(duration);
                      }
                      await sleep(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
                      node.requestFocus();
                    },
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 48
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Does `animationController.reset()` works?

Comment: Is it happening on correct or incorrect answers? You misspelled in question i think. Edit the questions please.

Comment: animationController.reset() actually worked, thanks @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset any animation controller, use [`animationController.reset()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController/reset.html).

> Sets the controller's value to lowerBound, stopping the animation (if in progress), and resetting to its beginning point, or dismissed state.

More about [`AnimationController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html).